# How to retreive one single item using Global Secondary Index in Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in Dynamodb and I'm trying to get an item (using `docClient.get`) by naming a Global Secondary Index but I'm getting the error:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

And here's my query:

```
docClient
    .get({
      TableName: 'table',,
      IndexName: 'gsi_table',
      Key: { primary_key }
    })
```

But then I looked at the [get documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) and it does not have an `IndexName` property. So I thought maybe I should name the GSI instead of the table name:

```
docClient
    .get({
      TableName: 'gsi_table',
      Key: { primary_key }
    })
```

But then I faced:

```
Requested resource not found
```

which means `gsi_table` is not recognized as a global table. So my question is, having the list of operations:

- batchGet
- batchWrite
- createSet
- delete
- get
- put
- query
- scan
- update

which ones support GSI and LSI? And also, if you want to retrieve one specific item using a GSI, which operation should you use? If I use `query`, am I actually doing things as fast/cheap as possible?

Answer (score 2):

[Secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) are for `Query` and `Scan` operations only. So, if you must use a global (or local) secondary index, then `Query` would be faster than `Scan`, of course.

To access your "single" item, you can use `data.Items[0]`. For example:

```
const params = {
    TableName: "TABLE_NAME",
    IndexName: "INDEX_NAME",
    KeyConditionExpression: "INDEX_KEY = :k",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":k": some_value
    }
};

docClient.query(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        const myItem = data.Items[0];
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have a comparison between the speed/cost of getting one item from base table and querying the GSI?

Comment: No, I don't think I do.